# How to show elements of Model 2 in show.html.erb of Model 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models PriceGroup, PriceGroupLine and Item.
PriceGroup has fields - :id and :name
Item has fields - :id and :name
PriceGroupLine has fields - :id, :price_group_id, :item_id, :price

Associations:

```
PriceGroup has_many PriceGroupLines

PriceGroupLine has_many Items

PriceGroupLine belongs_to PriceGroup
```

I need to show strings from PriceGroupLine model on show.html.erb of PriceGroup model. It looks like table (i can't post images - low reputation ((( ), ITEM - PRICE for current Price group. There is can be many PriceGroupLines in PriceGroup. They all must be shown for current Price Group.

I am new in Rails. Can you show me the way to solve my problem

UPDATE

I also need to insert in PriceGroupLine model lines from PriceGroup show view. How I should organize form_for helper if if I need to insert:

1. item_id - items list organized with collection_select helper
2. price_group_id
3. price of item

Here is my code of view show.html.erb of PriceGroup. Adding a new item in price group (through price group line) not working. undefined method 'price' for PriceGroup:0x007f7201dc0aa8 error

```
 <div class="container col-md-5">
    <h4>PriceGroup Info</h4>
    <%= link_to "Add new price group", new_price_group_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs", role: "button" %>
  <%= link_to "Back", price_groups_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs", role: "button" %>
    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Price Group name</strong></td>
        <td><%= @price_group.name %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <h4>Price Group Content</h4>

    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Price Group Name</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Price</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Operations</strong></td>
      </tr>
        <% @price_group.price_group_lines.each do |price_group_line| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= price_group_line.item.try(:name) %></td>
            <td><%= price_group_line.price %></td>
                <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_price_group_line_path(price_group_line), class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs", role: "button" %> | <%= link_to "Delete", price_group_line_path(price_group_line), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Sure?" }, class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs", role: "button" %></td>
            </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>  
</div>
<div class="container col-md-10">
  <h4>Add new item to PeiceGroup</h4>
  <%= form_for @price_group, html: {class: "form-inline"} do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Item</label>
            <%= f.collection_select(:id, Item.all, :id, :name, {}, {class: "form-control"}) %>
        </div> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Price</label>
            <%= f.text_field :price, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <%= f.submit "Add item", class: "btn btn-default" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a variable which has your pricegroup object named `@price_group`. So on the view what you can do is:

```
<% @price_group.price_group_lines.each do |price_group_line| %>
  <%= price_group_line.name %> #or anything you want to do
  <%= price_group_line.item.name %> #for the item name
<% end %>
```

Suppose you need comma separated values for a single attribute from `price_group_line` then you can also do it like this:

```
<%= @price_group.price_group_lines.map(&:name).join(', ') %>
```

This will give you all the names comma separated.

And as [Glupo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1303501/glupo) suggested you can have eager loading like this to avoid db requests on your views. So in your controller action:

```
@price_group = PriceGroup.find(params[:id]).include(:price_group_lines)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If doing so, please don't forget to include `price_group_lines` in select for your `@price_group` variable in order to remove DB request from view.
Something like `@proce_group = PriceGroup.find(params[:id]).include(:price_group_lines)`

Comment: Thank you for answer! Almost works! ))) PriceGroupLine has :item_id. How I can show Item's name??

Comment: When I added `.include(:price_group_lines)` it shows error: undefined method `include' for #<PriceGroup:0x007f2a2e42eb90>

Comment: @ArtB You can post your controller code so we can help

Comment: I used the code in answer. In view I see not a name, just "Item". Maybe I have error in associations?

Comment: May be you don't have item in `price_group_line` or the `item` doesn't has name.

Comment: Direct SQL request to database `select items.name
 from price_group_lines 
left join items on (items.id = price_group_lines.item_id)` shows name correctly

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem. But I still have one question. I changed the associations. Now `PriceGroupLine belongs_to :item` and `Item has_one :price_group_line`. But it is logical to assume that ITEM is belongs to PriceGroupLine (PRICEGROUPLINE contains ITEM). Am I wrong?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Your update is bit unclear to me, you should have tried something, paste that code of view what you have done and the error you are getting we can help you then. And if it can be a new question that would be better as other SO users can also help you if I am offline